# How an IERC can do transferFrom without ERC20?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Recipient {
    IERC20 private _token;

    event DoneStuff(address from, address to, uint256 amount);

    constructor (address token) public {
        _token = IERC20(token);
    }

    function doStuff() external {
        address from = msg.sender;
        address to = address(this);
        uint256 amount = 1e18;

        _token.transferFrom(from, to, amount);
        emit DoneStuff(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

Here, the contract imports the IERC20 which is just an interface. I'm trying to understand why the contract can execute this `_token.transferFrom(from, to, amount);` without having the actual transferFrom function? Because the contract just imports the interface and does not have the transferFrom function implemented.

Could you help me clear my mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a function from another contract the compiler needs the target address, function signature and parameters.

At runtime the EVM will locate the contract's bytecode and execute the required function with the passed parameters.

Comment: It means that the `_token` is the existing contract that has `transferFrom` function? And this contract is just calling the "transferFrom" funciton from contract `token`? Am I right?

Comment: @Ender Yes, exactly.